# Learning to Becoming a Hadoop Administrator

Tags: linux, hadoop, administrator

I would like to become a Hadoop administrator. I have a copy of the book 'Hadoop Operations' and i would like to get my hands dirty with setups et al.

So here's the question: Should i invest in a physical server for practice? or is it all done in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't invest in a physical server, unless you're sure (and I mean SURE) you want to spend hundreds of CPU-hours in practical exercises.  A more cost-effective option may be to get an account with a IaaS provider (such as Amazon), and experiment with virtual machines.  You can turn off unneeded VMs when not doing exercises, so your costs could be a lot smaller.  Plus you can get many VMs for short periods of time without huge upfront investments.

Some of the most challenging aspects of administering Hadoop is dealing with large clusters and clusters that are highly utilized.  Unfortunately this means that there is only so much you can learn on your own, as both of those scenarios can be very expensive and time-consuming to set up.  So don't try going too deep on your toy cluster, instead get familiar with the basics & configuration options and then try to find a job, or a project where you could join an existing ops team.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I have decided to go the cloud route. OpenStack to be specific. I attempt ordering hardware. but the more i bought, the more absurd it became.